# How to prove thus statement for a square matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, adjacency-matrix

$A$ is a square matrix
I have to prove that $$A\cdot \textrm{adj}(A)=\textrm{adj}(A)\cdot A=\det(A)\cdot I$$
without using the inverse of $A$.

Comment: This has got to be in almost every single linear algebra textbook?

Comment: @copper.hat they always prove it using the inverse of A. I’m not allowed to do that

Comment: Use continuity then?

Comment: Check this: http://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104018/node29.html

Comment: @EugenCovaci okay thank youu

Comment: @EugenCovaci: That is a fairly succinct proof.

Comment: You can also find this at ProofWiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Matrix_Product_with_Adjugate_Matrix

Comment: @barto thanks a lot